# Can Instruments be corrupting memory?

Tags: ios, instruments, unrecognized-selector

As I move my next version of my app closer to submitting to the store I run a leak check on it using Instruments.  On all of my test devices (iPod touch, iPhone, iPad; different OS levels, etc.) all is well, except on an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3, where the app crashes 75% of the time.

The device logs are showing a commonality... that doesn't make any sense to me.

The crashes are all of the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" variety, so to limit your need to scroll, I'll remove the front part of the message so you can see the commonality more easily.

The first run crashed with this:

```
reason: '-[UIDeviceWhiteColor clean]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f84db50'
```

The second run ran fine.

The third run crashed with this:

```
reason: '-[CALayer clean]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f87fab0'
```

The fourth run crashed with this variation:

```
reason: '-[UIImage clean]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e56b9d0'
```

Lest you think I might be calling some private Apple APIs like a UIDeviceWhiteColor object, I'm not.  I have no idea where that is coming from.  At the time of the crash a network connection is supposed to be being created between this app and another one on the network that this app discovered using service discovery.  The Connection class does in fact have a -clean method, but the only calls to that method are within the Connection class and they all are of the [self clean] variety -- so it's hard to see how -clean could be an unrecognized selector sent to oneself.

stackoverflow suggests [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261879/a-phantom-memory-leak-with-arc-in-xcode-4-5-where-dealloc-is-definitely-called-o) may be at play when something only happens while Instruments is profiling the app, but I'm unclear how that would apply here.

**Can anybody help explain what I am really seeing versus what are the red herrings?**

P.S. The reason I ask if Instruments could be corrupting memory is because of cobweb-memories about Objective C's method dispatch table, and the three crashes all referencing weird and weirdly different objects, as if the dispatch table were getting corrupted.

P.S.S. I cold booted the iPhone 4S between the third and fourth runs.  I've also quit both Instruments and Xcode to make sure they weren't twisted up.